# Use .filter within a function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a function that creates a pivot table, and I need to filter one column based on a string.

```
df = DataFrame({'Breed': ['Sheltie', 'Bernard', 'Husky', 'Husky', 'pig', 'Sheltie','Bernard'], 
            'Metric': ['One month walked', 'two month walked', 'three month walked', 'four month walked', 'one month waiting', 'two month waiting', 'Three month waiting'],
            'Age': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
```

I want a pivot table with the ages of all the dogs summed up, where they have a 'completed' metric, regardless of what month.

It would look a little something like this:

```
                             Age
Breed      Metric            sum
------------------------------------
Husky  one month walked       4
Husky  four month walked      5
```

The function would filter out any of the metrics that are not 'walked', while summing up each of the 'completed' metric.

I've been trying this so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import fnmatch

def Dog_Walked_Completed(dfprime):
    return dfprime[dfprime['Breed'] == 'Husky'].groupby(['Breed','Metric']).fnmatch.filter(lambda df : (df['Metric']=='?completion')).any().agg({'Age': ['sum']})
```

But whenever i try that, I get a ''DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'fnmatch' error. Is there a different way to do wildcard searches within a function?

Comment: You're missing a bunch of `)` at the end of the line.

Comment: Actually you have other unclosed brackets.

Comment: Basically, it looks like you started writing what you wanted, then just gave up in the middle of the code.

Comment: Hard to fix your code ...

Comment: Ah! Sorry, long day. I fixed the code and updated it based on the new problem I encountered.

Comment: where is x defined?

Comment: Updated it to 'husky' to work with the sample data frame in the above.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hey, I updated with the expected output. Sorry for all the confusion, I was in a rush when making this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming to want to find the sum of ages for each breed, which completion word in their metric. You can take the following approach.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Breed': ['Sheltie', 'Bernard', 'Husky', 'Husky', 'pig', 'Sheltie','Bernard'],'Metric': ['One month walked', 'two month walked', 'three month walked', 'four month walked', 'one month waiting', 'two month waiting', 'Three month waiting'],'Age': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
>>> df
   Age    Breed               Metric
0    1  Sheltie     One month walked
1    2  Bernard     two month walked
2    3    Husky   three month walked
3    4    Husky    four month walked
4    5      pig    one month waiting
5    6  Sheltie    two month waiting
6    7  Bernard  Three month waiting
```

Now lets create boolean function which check for the word completion in the `Metrics` column of the dataframe `df`.

```
>>> bool = df['Metric'].str.contains('completion')
```

Now you can do `groupby` on the Breed and `bool` variable to find the sum of ages.

```
>>> pvt_tbl = df.groupby(['Breed',bool])['Age'].sum()
>>> pvt_tbl
Breed    Metric
Bernard  False     9
Husky    False     7
Sheltie  False     7
pig      False     5
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

Since there was no 'completion' word in the sample data, all were returned false. But we can check for 'walked' word as there are some rows where walked is present.

```
>>> bool1 = df['Metric'].str.contains('walked')
>>> pvt_tbl1 = df.groupby(['Breed',bool1])['Age'].sum()
>>> pvt_tbl1
Breed    Metric
Bernard  False     7
         True      2
Husky    True      7
Sheltie  False     6
         True      1
pig      False     5
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

Hope , this is what you want to do.

**Update**
As per comments:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Breed','Metric'])['Age'].sum()
Breed    Metric
Bernard  Three month waiting    7
         two month walked       2
Husky    four month walked      4
         three month walked     3
Sheltie  One month walked       1
         two month waiting      6
pig      one month waiting      5
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help, and apologies for the lack of meaningful instructions. For the Breed column, I'm looking to create a dframe for each breed by itself, hence the function since on my real dataframe I'm working with 100+ 'breeds. For the metric column, I'm looking to return the string itself, as opposed to a boolean. Thank you for your patience.